# Error sending array of inputs

Tags: query-posts, taxonomy, search

Hello I am getting a Error of the Wordpress includes, this error appears when I post the multiple values of a taxonomy

```
<form role="search" method="post" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">

<select name="books[]" multiple>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**Warning**:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in  **www.domain.com\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php** on line **1718**

**Warning**:  preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in  **www.domain.com\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php** on line **1719**

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  **www.domain.com\wordpress\wp-includes\query.php** on line **1720**

```
    foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_taxonomies'] as $taxonomy => $t ) {
        if ( 'post_tag' == $taxonomy )
            continue;   // Handled further down in the $q['tag'] block

        if ( $t->query_var && !empty( $q[$t->query_var] ) ) {
            $tax_query_defaults = array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
            );

            if ( isset( $t->rewrite['hierarchical'] ) && $t->rewrite['hierarchical'] ) {
                $q[$t->query_var] = wp_basename( $q[$t->query_var] );
            }

            $term = $q[$t->query_var];

            if ( strpos($term, '+') !== false ) {
                $terms = preg_split( '/[+]+/', $term );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $tax_query[] = array_merge( $tax_query_defaults, array(
                        'terms' => array( $term )
                    ) );
                }
            } else {
                $tax_query[] = array_merge( $tax_query_defaults, array(
                    'terms' => preg_split( '/[,]+/', $term )
                ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

The error does not appear when I post it to searchresults.php or when I use when I use a single value or a none taxonomy name;

```
<select name="books">
<select name="NoneTaxonomyName[]" multiple>
```

does someone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved with; **query_var => false**

```
register_taxonomy('taxname', 'post_type', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'lable',     'query_var' => false, 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'slug')));
```

Comment: That is a poor workaround. Setting query_var to false will made permalinks to terms pages return 404 error. Other solutions is needed if the terms pages are needed in the frontend, as it is my case.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment above, setting `query_var => false` for the custom taxonomy is not a solution because this will make term pages in frontend return a 404 error. Renounce to term pages in the frontend to make a simple form to work is far away to be a solution.

Finally I've solved the problem. Instead of set the name in the select element to 'my_tax[]', I've set it to something like 'tax_input['my_tax'][]. Don't ask me why Wordpress needs this, but it fix the problem.

Just if someone needs an example.

My sample taxonomies:

```
$taxonomies = array(
            'type'               => array('label' => 'Types','slug' => 'type','hierarchical' => false,'multiple' => false),
            'city'               => array('label' => 'Cities','slug' => 'city','hierarchical' => true,'multiple' => false),
            'community_features' => array('label' => 'Community features','slug' => 'community_features','hierarchical' => false,'multiple' => true),
            'property_features'  => array('label' => 'Property features','slug' => 'property_features','hierarchical' => false,'multiple' => true)
    ); 

   foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy => $properties){
        register_taxonomy(
                         $taxonomy,
                         'properties',
                         array(
                              'label'        => __( $properties['label'] ),
                              'hierarchical' => $properties['hierarchical'],
                              'query_var'    => true,
                              )
                          );

         register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, 'properties' );

}
```

Here a sample form:

```
           <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('properties');?>">
             <?php
               foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
                   $args = array(
                                'show_option_all'    => __('Select '.$taxonomy['label'],'properties'),
                                'orderby'            => 'NAME', 
                                'order'              => 'ASC',
                                'hide_empty'         => 0, 
                                'echo'               => 0,
                                'selected'           => '',
                                'hierarchical'       => true, 
                                'name'               => 'tax_input['.$taxonomy['slug'].'][]',
                                'class'              => '',
                                'taxonomy'           => $taxonomy['slug'],
                             );

                 if($taxonomy['multiple']){
                   $args['show_option_all'] = '';
                 }
                 $select = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

                 if($taxonomy['multiple']){
                   $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 multiple>", $select);
                 }

                 echo $select;
               }
             ?>
             <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="search">
             <button type="submit"><?php _e('Search','properties');?></button>
           </form>
```

Added a custom query var:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'properties_add_query_vars');
function properties_add_query_vars( $vars) {
   $vars[] = "action"; // name of the var as seen in the URL
   return $vars;
}
```

An my sample pre_get_posts:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'properties_pre_get_post' );
function properties_pre_get_post($query){

  if(isset($query->query_vars['action']) && $query->query_vars['action'] == 'search'){

     if($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && $query->is_archive ) {

        $tax_query = array();

        $tax_input = $_POST['tax_input'];
        if(!empty($tax_input)){

           foreach($tax_input as $key => $value){
              if(array_key_exists($key, $taxonomies)){
                 if(!empty($value) && $value[0] != "0"){
                    $value = array_map('intval', $value);
                $tax_query[] = array(
                                         'taxonomy' => $key,
                                         'field'    => 'id',
                                         'terms'    => $value,
                                         'operator' => 'AND'
                                   );
                 }
              }
            }
         $query->set('tax_query',$tax_query);
       }
    }
  }
}
```